# Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody?

Tags: java, syntax-error

For some reason I get a syntax error that says, "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody." I checked every method, every statement to make sure I have complete opening and closing brackets, so I don't know why this is happening. Can anybody tell me why I might be getting this issue?

Copying the code into another file doesn't fix the problem, nor does going to Project > Clean.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class jloneman_Numerology
{
    private String[] report;
    private int day, month, year, num;

    public jloneman_Numerology()
    {
        introduction();
        report = new String[9];
        num = 0;
    }

    public void introduction()
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to ACME Numerology Reports! We will " +
                "determine your special\nnumerology report based on your " +
                "birth date.\n");
    }

    public void getDate()
    {
        char slash1, slash2;

        do
        {
            System.out.print("Please enter your birth date (mm / dd / yyyy): ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            String date = in.nextLine();

            month = in.nextInt();
            day = in.nextInt();
            year = in.nextInt();

            slash1 = date.charAt(3);
            slash2 = date.charAt(8);
        } while (validDate(slash1, slash2) == false);

        calcNum();
    }

    public boolean validDate(char slash1, char slash2)
    {
        boolean isValid = true;

        // Check for valid month
        if (month < 1 || month > 12) 
        {
            isValid = false;
            System.out.printf("Invalid month: %d\n", month);
        }

        // Check for valid day
        if (day < 1 || day > 31)
        {
            isValid = false;
            System.out.printf("Invalid day: %d\n", day);
        }

        // Check for months with 30 days, else 31 days = invalid
        if ((month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) && (day < 1 || day > 30))
        {
            isValid = false;
            System.out.printf("Invalid day: %d\n", day);
        }
        else if (day < 1 || day > 31)
        {
            isValid = false;
            System.out.printf("Invalid day: %d\n", day);
        }

        // Check for valid year
        if (year < 1880 || year > 2280) 
        {
            isValid = false;
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid year between 1880 and 2280.");
        }

        // Check for correct separating character
        if (slash1 != '/' || slash2 != '/')
        {
            isValid = false;
            System.out.println("Invalid separating character, please use forward slashes");
        }

        if (leapYear() == true)
        {
            if (month == 2 && day > 29)
            {
                isValid = false;
                System.out.printf("Invalid day for 2/%d: %d", year, day);
            }
        }

        return isValid;
    }

    public boolean leapYear()
    {
        boolean isLeap;

        if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 400 != 0)
            isLeap = false;
        else
            isLeap = true;

        return isLeap;
    }

    public void calcNum()
    {
        // Separate each digit of the date and add to a single number

        // Test number for debugging
        num = 5;
    }

    public void printReport()
    {
        report[0] = ":1: ";
        report[1] = ":2: ";
        report[2] = ":3: ";
        report[3] = ":4: ";
        report[4] = ":5: ";
        report[5] = ":6: ";
        report[6] = ":7: ";
        report[7] = ":8: ";
        report[8] = ":9: ";

        System.out.println(report[num]);
    }
}

                                                                                                                                                  78,0-1        Bot
```

Comment: i copied your code into my workspace, and i see no compiler errors of any sort :P

Comment: It looks fine - did you show all the content of that file? Is the file named `jloneman_Numerology.java`?

Comment: What is that `78,0-1        Bot` at the end of your code? Is it culprit? I suspect so. Let us know in any case. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing (or commenting out) one method and see if the problem persists.  If it does, remove or comment out an additional method, and so on, until the error disappears.  Then restore everything but the last method.

If the error doesn't reappear, the problem is probably in that last method.

If it *does* reappear, the problem is more subtle; perhaps a control character embedded in the code.  Try copying and pasting the code into a text-only editor (so any control characters will be ignored, save it, and recompiling.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this error.
There are NO errors in the code above (when I used the code above as as a sub class).
I corrected my error by cleaning up my IDE's workspace and making sure the caller was working properly.

- Project settings
- Run settings
- Made sure that main was listed properly
- public static void main(String[] args) { ... }

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the similar problem, solved it by deleting the class file and then recreated the file again and pasted the same code. It worked.

Answer (score -1):

Take out the `System.out.println` and put it into the main function instead of the `introduction()` inside of the `main(String[] args)`.